# Can someone please provide the meaning and source of Durga Mantra Om Dum Durgayei Namaha?

Tags: mantras, durga

Can someone please provide the meaning and source of Durga Mantra Om Dum Durgayei Namaha? What is the meaning of the beej akshar Dum? Why is the suffix -yei added after Durga?

Can you please state the scripture/source where this mantra first appeared?

Comment: There no reason to understand what beeja Akshara mean. It cannot be found and there is no reason why we should find one. The suffix -yei also has no meaning expect when attached along with durga, it's also present in navakshari. Siddhi kunjika verse 11- "यैकारी वर-दायिनी" (in the form of -yei she is the boon giver or fullfils the wishes)

Comment: @Proxy I agree that dum is surely a bījākṣara and has no definition as such, but दुर्गायै is perfectly regular, it's the dative singular of दुर्गा (i.e. *to* Durga), as required by नमः It's the equivalent of रामाय नमः (not राम नमः) and गणेशाय नमः (not गणेश नमः). Other examples would be सीतायै (to/for Sita), लतायै (to/for the vine) etc.

Comment: @Proxy- Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @Au101- Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Au101 yes you are correct!